# Equating two struct but want to change one of the fields

Tags: c

I am equating two structs num1 and num. What I would like to do is change one of the fields of num1 without changing other fields that is rest of the fields should be equal to the fields of num. But the following code ends up changing both fields of num and num1. Can someone please give a reason ?.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    typedef struct
    { 
        int one;
        int two;
    }Num;

    Num *num;
    Num *num1;
    num=malloc(sizeof(Num));
    num->one=1;
    num->two=2;
   // num1=malloc(sizeof(Num));
    num1=num;
    num1->one=10;
    //num1->two=2;

    printf("%d %d\n",num1->one,num->one);
    return 0;
}
```

I know an alternate way. Allocate memory for num1. Equate all the fields of num to num1 except the ones I want to change. Is there any other way ?.

Comment: "two structs". You don't have two structs. You have two pointers to the same struct.

Comment: You know both `num` and `num1` are pointers, right?

Comment: Yes I do know that they are pointers to the structures. Is there any other way other than the way which I mentioned to change the fields of num1 ? @sourav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two pointers `num` and `num1` which point to the same structure.So changing the struct via `num` will change the struct pointed by `num1` also(since they are pointing to the same thing).

```
 num = malloc(sizeof(Num));
 num1 = malloc(sizeof(Num));
```

Now `num` and `num1` point to different structs.

```
num->one=1;
num->two=2;
*num1 = *num;
num1->two = 3;
```

Comment: Cool !. Thanks @Gaurav

Comment: @Lundin can you please elaborate.

Comment: It seems as if you recommend to do two malloc calls and then set `num1` to point at something else other than the allocated memory.

Comment: typo: `mallloc`. (Unless that's a fancy allocator API I don't know about). And did you mean `*num1 = *num;`?

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating memory for `num1` at all. You are just making an alias of the variable `num` there. Without using `malloc` or any other memory allocating functions you can't expect deep copies or clones of one particular structure or object. Try this.

```
num1=malloc(sizeof(Num));
memcpy (num1, num, sizeof (num1));
```

The function `memcpy` helps you clone variables making deep copies.The format of `memcpy` is as below

```
memcpy(destination_var, source_var, sizeof (destination_var));
```

Comment: I don't think memcpy does a deep copy (may be in this case it does). What if the num were to contain pointers ? @sameera

Comment: @ArunSrikanthSridhar I meant deep copies prevail if you have values inside the variables. Just gave him an option of doing that as he had no pointers as values. we'll have to write a clone method ourselves if we have pointers

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate separate memory for each num and num1 to have separate values in it.
To avoid malloc, just declare variable like below and try the code

```
Num num;
Num num1;

num.one=1;
num.two=2;

num1=num;
num1.one=10;
//num1.two=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please forget everything said so far and do like this:

```
num=malloc(sizeof(Num));
num1=malloc(sizeof(Num));

num->one=1;
num->two=2;

*num1 = *num; // copy all of the contents

num1->one=10; // change individual members if needed

...
free(num);
free(num1);
```

Comment: Will this work (*num1=*num) in case if the struct contains pointer or dynamically allocated arrays ? @Lundin. Thanks

Comment: @ArunSrikanthSridhar No, in that case you won't get a deep copy. You'd have to allocate memory for the copy of the pointed-at data and then adjust all pointers.